# search for keywords in file directory

Tags: python, os.walk, os.path

I'm having difficulties to find the filenames that contain a keyword from a predetermined list. I manage to find all files from the directory and subdirectories, however finding keywords is not functioning. I would like to list all the files in my directory that contain a keyword in it's name:

```
path = ':O drive'
keywords = ['photo', 'passport', 'license']
files = [] # list of all files in directory
result = []  # list store our results

#list all files
for root, directories, file_path in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in file_path:
            files.append(os.path.join(root, name))

#find keywords in files            
for filename in files:
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in filename:
            result[keyword].os.path.join(path, filename)

print(result)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `result` to be something like a `defaultdict(list)` rather than a list, and then you can do `result[keyword].append(os.path.join(path,filename))`

Comment: Can you please try this?
`if keyword in str(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use glob for this, subbing the pattern with the keyword for each loop.  This would create a dict of lists.  In this case I have 1 file named `photo.txt` and 2 files named `license 2019.txt` and `license 2020.txt` in the working directory of the script.

```
from glob import glob
import os
keywords = ['photo','license', 'passport']

path = './'

output = {}
for word in keywords:
    output[word] = glob(os.path.join(path,f'*{word}*'))
```

Output

```
{'photo': ['.\\photo.txt'],
 'license': ['.\\license 2019.txt', '.\\license 2020.txt'],
 'passport': []}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, it won't find files that are in subdirectories. How could I apply the '#list all files' part in my code to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of filenames that contain **any** of the keywords in your list, try list comprehension:

```
result = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files if any(k in f.lower() for k in keywords)]
```

If you want a dictionary, do this instead:

```
result = dict()
for k in keywords:
    result[k] = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files if k in f.lower()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> keywords = ['photo', 'passport', 'license']
>>> m = re.findall(f"^.*[{'|'.join(keywords)}].*$", 'example-photo.jpg')
>>> m
['example-photo.jpg']
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(":O drive"): 
  keywords=['photo', 'passport', 'license','file']
  for filename in files:
    f = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
    for keyword in keywords:        
      if keyword in f:
          try:
            print(f)
          except OSError as e:
            print("Error: %s : %s" % (f, e.strerror))
```

This is my proposed solution to your problem. And it also shows the full path of the file we are searching for, with try and catch if something unusual happens.